# How to get the orderId from the braintree result

Tags: node.js, braintree

Here is the result from the braintree checkout.

```
{ transaction: 
   Transaction {
     id: '7h534h3r',
     status: 'settling',
     type: 'sale',
     currencyIsoCode: 'USD',
     amount: '15.00',
     merchantAccountId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
     subMerchantAccountId: null,
     masterMerchantAccountId: null,
     orderId: '5b98025f09dd1231e4596c95',
     createdAt: '2018-09-04T04:40:04Z',
     updatedAt: '2018-09-04T04:40:08Z'
......
```

I'd like to get the orderID. I have used the result.transaction.Transaction.orderID but failed. I finally realized that there is a missing colon(:) after the "Transaction". How could I get the orderId from it? Thanks in advance.

Richard Xu

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the "Transaction" is just the type and not a property. Try result.transaction.orderId